# Custom JsonConverter attributes not working with Json.Serialize() using Newtonsoft.JSON in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to use Newtonsoft Json.NET to perform de/serialization in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. I've put the following in my startup ConfigureServices code:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I've got an MVC model with custom serialization attributes:

```
public class MyModel {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomJsonConverter))]
    public DateTime MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

In my view I serialize it to JSON:

```
<script>
    someJsFunction(@Json.Serialize(Model));
</script>
```

But it doesn't use MyCustomJsonConverter. Breakpoints aren't hit in MyCustomJsonConverter.

An answer might be to add to the global Json settings:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter>()
        {
            new MyCustomJsonConverter()
        };

    });
```

But then MyCustomJsonConverter is applied to every DateTime property rather than just the ones with the attribute applied. I could also use the JSON.Serialize overload:

```
<script>
    someJsFunction(@Json.Serialize(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings()
                                           {
                                               Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new MyCustomJsonConverter()},       
                                           }
                                  ));
</script>
```

But I don't want to do this every time I call it. I'm pretty sure these JsonConverter attributes worked fine by themselves before the switch away from Newtonsoft Json.NET in 3.0. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view add using for Newtonsoft and use its Serializer.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

...

..(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```

The reason is not working is that you are using Serializers from different libraries one from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` and the other from `Newtonsoft.Json`