# NewtonSoft JsonConverter not firing in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working with a Web API which retrieves data from an Elasticsearch database. The database is populated by an entirely different piece of software which I cannot modify. One of the fields in the data, `metatag.description`, is supposed to be populated with a single value, but sometimes ends up with an array of values because of errors in the upstream data. (I cannot modify those either, it's a collection of ~200 web sites.)

The inconsistent data structure was previously handled by adding a custom `JsonConverter` to the relevant member of the model.

After updating the project from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 3.1, the custom `JsonConverter` is no longer being called when the object is deserialized from Elasticsearch.

The project file references the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.*" />
```

Newtonsoft.Json is initialized in `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

A cutdown version of the model looks like this (the full file includes `using Newtonsoft.Json;`). The model has a single `Description` field, but sometimes the upstream data source sends an array instead of a single value. (We can't reasonably fix the upstream source.)

```
public class SiteWideSearchResult
{
    [Text(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Text(Name = "metatag.description")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MetadataDescriptionConverter))]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The `JsonConverter` currently looks like this, but none of these lines are executed, nor are any breakpoints reached when set (this full file also includes `using Newtonsoft.Json;`):

```
public class MetadataDescriptionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As described above, there are two versions of the structure being deserialized. The `JsonConverter` is meant to handle both and allow a (potentially altered) version of the data be stored in the model.

Because it matches the model, this version deserializes correctly:

```
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "item_id_1",
        "_score": 4.3536105,
        "_source": {
          "metatag.description": "Single description entry",
          "title": "This structure works"
        }
      }
```

This version is meant to be handled by the custom `JsonConverter`. As it is, it fails.

```
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "item_id_2",
        "_score": 4.3536105,
        "_source": {
          "metatag.description": [
             "First description line",
             "Second description line"
          ],
          "title": "This structure fails"
        }
      }
```

The error from the second structure is `expected:'String Begin Token', actual:'['` which makes sense, but that's what the converter is meant to address. Except, it's not being invoked.

I suspect the `System.Text.Json` serializer is being used instead of the one from `Newtonsoft.Json`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59344272/282194) seems to suggest adding Newtonsoft in the `ConfigureServices` and the `using` statements isn't sufficient. The answer's terseness however leaves me unclear what needs to change (I *think* it's Razor markup). I've found no documentation suggesting anything similar for a webapi (Possibly that's an attribute? Which is what I'm already using).

**Things I've tried**

- As written, the model and converter do work with .Net 2.1, but it occurs to me that the deserializer in the newer version of Nest might stop because `Description` is decorated with `[Text]`. I've tried changing it to `[Nested]` without success.
- Removing the mapping attribute altogether and using `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "metatag.description", ItemConverter = typeof(MetadataDescriptionConverter))]`. No difference.
- Using the JsonConverter attribute on the entire `SiteWideSearchResult` model, but that also doesn't execute the converter. (Nor does it hit any breakpoints in the converter.)

Comment: I am trying to understand what is the problem? What is your question? You have two completely different json and you are trying to deserilize it using one the same class?

Comment: @Serge - the problem is that the JsonConverter isn't being fired. I should make this clearer, but the converter is meant to reconcile the difference between the two structures.

Comment: I still don' t understand what is all about Why are trying to make such a simple stuff so complicated. Maybe you have to post the whole code including API and how you get this jasons.

Comment: A custom `JsonConverter` is (at least with aspnet 2.1) the simplest way I've found to handle the case where I need to tweak the deserialization and convert an array of strings into a single value. I'm open to an alternative. Otherwise, my assumption is that I'm misunderstanding something about the intersection of Elasticsearch, serialization, and aspnet 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core change from `Newtonsoft.JSON` to the native `System.Text.Json.Serialization` is a red-herring.

The actual culprit is a change to the version 7.x of the Elasticsearch NEST client. **[As of version 7.0, NEST no longer uses Newtonsoft.Json internally](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html)**.

For the specific case of deserializing on when retrieving data from Elasticsearch, it appears the correct approach is to specify a custom  serializer as described on that page.

**For my particular use case**, the solution is to use the [JsonNetSerializer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer) by adding `sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default` in the call to the `ConnectionSettings` constructor.

```
var connectionSettings =
    new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: JsonNetSerializer.Default);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

On the other hand, if the need for custom mapping extends to index creation time, the custom ["Visitor Pattern mapping"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html) may be more appropriate.